# Perl module version information in the BEGIN block

Tags: perl

In some CPAN modules I found the next construction

```
BEGIN {
    $Package::Name::VERSION = "N.N";
}
```

What is a rationale behind putting the package version information into the `BEGIN` block?

for example: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JSWARTZ/Poet-0.12/lib/Poet/Cache.pm

EDIT - in the [most recent module](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JSWARTZ/Poet-0.15/lib/Poet/Cache.pm) version it is pulled out, but anyway - it was here - so wondering why it is good (or bad) :)

Comment: Care to include specific examples where you've seen this?  The short answer is so that other initialization steps can refer to it in error messages without risk of it not being set.  Also, it doesn't hurt anything even if it is potentially superfluous.  I believe there's another reason related to parsing the module for the version number, but I forget the details of that.

Comment: @Miller Don't understand why do you need specific example for the answer, but ok - added one ;)

Comment: Because different modules might be doing it for different reasons (some might just be copy and paste), therefore it's helpful to talk about a specific case.  Also, my brain works quicker when looking at actual code ;)  I know there's a historical reason behind this, but I don't recall it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one of those things that everyone has always done and can't remember why!

Essentially it is because `use` statements allow multiple modules to be in compilation at the same time, so although it looks like a module is complete it may have only just started compiling.

Any code being compiled can check the value of `$Module::VERSION` by using the inherited `UNIVERSAL::VERSION` subroutine, which is already defined implicitly before a module even starts compiling.

Remember that, if `Module.pm` contains

```
use Another::Module;
```

Then compilation of `Module.pm` is put on hold while `Another/Module.pm` is compiled.

There is nothing to stop `Another::Module` from doing

```
use Module 1.5;
```

which will call `Module::VERSION(1.5)` (inherited from `UNIVERSAL::VERSION`) to check that `$Module::VERSION` is 1.5 or greater.

If `$Module::VERSION` is defined outside a `BEGIN` block, it won't be set until after all `use` statements have been completed, and so too late for other modules to do version checking on `Module`.

I hope this is clear. I can't help thinking there must be a simpler explanation, but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: So, it helps when looking for the "`use` specific module version". Greatly explained - only wondering, why Johnatan pulled out the VERSION from the BEGIN in the most recent modules version... but this is not a question for you :) :) thanx.

Comment: @Miller: It's nothing to do with `Exporter`: you want to look at `use.pm`.

Comment: *nod*, that's why I removed the part about Exporter from my comment.  Think my brain can't handle diving into the specifics of this anymore, but it's a good question/suggested answer.